# Installing my application to my phone

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have a problem with installing my application to my phone for second time, I set USB debugging and stay awake in the developer setting. For the first time I install and use my app correctly but after I uninstall it by phone and reinstall again by android studio this error has occurred:
[image: 1]

Comment: pressing ok did not solve the issue?

Comment: when a first version is installed from a computer, sometimes the same application modified cannot be installed when built from another computer. Anyhow, try to uninstall manually the app before installing again if pressing OK is not enough

Comment: Press OK and it will install the new compile apk file and remove the apk that have been install from some other source

Comment: I press OK and it has an error for me..that it can't be install and FAILED...

Comment: no...but I can fix this by cleaning Project...thank you very much _ @AbdulWaheed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this in Android Studio and all I did to fix it was go to "Build" > "Clean Project" and it just worked.

Comment: I accepted but It don't let me to upvote because of my reputation that is less 15..sorry...

Comment: @MahdiMostafavi no problem I may help you in getting some reputation  :)

Answer (score 0):

Its due to your device is not able to uninstall the application properly, try to reboot once it may solve your issue. Also try to clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the app from device. Then rebuild and install

Answer (score 0):

Go to the apps option in settings in your phone and see if the application is still listed there . Search the entire list, it could be on the bottom of the list. Remove from there and then you could install the app from studio.